# Import svelte html file into js file using rollup

Tags: javascript, rollupjs, svelte

Js file:

```
import template from './Template.html';

class VacationListForCompany extends HTMLElement {

constructor() {
    super();
    const root = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});

    const t = new template({ target: root });

  }
}

window.customElements.define("vacation-list-for-company", 
VacationListForCompany);
```

Svelte/HTML file

```
<h1> This is from SVELTE </h1>
<script>
    export default {
    };
</script>
```

And in my Rollupfile 
    import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';

```
export default {
   input: 'Widgets/VacationListForCompany/widget.js',
   output: {
      format: 'iife',
      file: 'dist/vacationlistforcompany.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte({ include:'*.html'})
  ],
};
```

[image]

Seems like rollup is not able to generate svelte component on import.. 
Am I missunderstanding something here?

Comment: btw I'm using Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

By default, Svelte compiles the HTML file into a Svelte component.  [See the docs for the Svelte component API](https://svelte.technology/guide#component-api).

To generate a custom element instead, you need to pass `customelement: true` to the compiler (in your case, by setting it in the options passed to `rollup-plugin-svelte`). [See PR 797](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/797)

Comment: Thaks for your answer, but... that was not my queston :) I am aware of that, but I want to create the custom element my self.. And just use svelte as the internal "engine" for generating it.

Comment: import template from './Template.html';  <-- this is the line that is failing

Answer (score 0):

It was of cource an error from my side... the

```
svelte({ include:'*.html'})
```

for some reason is misspelled, removing this made it work..

Comment: `include` should be a glob pattern — to catch all HTML files it should be `**/*.html`. (But removing `include` altogether does the same thing, since that's the default.)